# Laravel: 2nd level relationship only fetching single row

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I am using Laravel 5.6 and I have relation between 3 tables. Cart->cartItem->Images
Here is my controller code:

```
$cart = Cart::where('created_by_id', Auth::user()->id)->with('cartDetails')->first();
```

Here is my cart model:

```
public function CartItem()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Http\models\CartItem', 'cart_id')->with('images');
    }
```

Here is the model of cartItem:

```
public function images()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Http\models\ProductImage', 'item_id', 'product_id');
    }
```

Now in result I am getting only single image even though I have multiple images in the database. It always picking up the last inserted image.
I want to get all images or at least the first one but not the last one. 
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have multiple images in the database of items then you have to use `hasMany()` insted of `belongsTo()`.

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Http\models\ProductImage', 'item_id', 'product_id');
}
```

**When use** `belongTo()` ?

suppose you have post and comment model. Now you want **post of comment** . That is  inverse of a hasMany relationship.To define the inverse of a hasMany relationship, define a relationship function on the Comment (child) model which calls the belongsTo method

```
 public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `hasMany()` relation instead of `belongsTo()`:

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Http\models\ProductImage', 'item_id', 'product_id');
}
```